# using a form values to create an account on another website

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have the following code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Registration Form</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["uname"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["pass"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("UserName must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    if (y == null || y == "") {
        alert("Password must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <h2> Register new GreenHouse </h2>
    <div>
    <form id="login" name= "myForm" method="put" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <fieldset id="inputs">
            <input name="uname" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>   
            <input name="pass" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to use values of username and password and create a new account at another website (such as yahoo or google). I am not quite sure how to start doing this. The basic idea when someone fill in the text-boxes a new account with the same userID and password (as they put in) will be created for them. I would be glad if someone could show me the way or show me a tutorial about this.

Comment: Let me clarify: you want your site to create an account for the user at another site (not your own site)? So they fill in a form on your webpage and the result is a Google account?

Comment: For example if you want Google, see the HTML of [this](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp)

Comment: Yes I want this form to create account for users on another site. Actually the other site also belong to me, but this form is a separate thing and I want the people that using this form to be able to create account on the website. I wast want them to type in the id and password and when they click submit a new account is created for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ethical and possibly legal (as well as technical) issues surrounding the creation of a user account on Google or Yahoo in the manner you suggest. The user should just create the account directly.

You can move forward, though, by tidying up your Javascript as follows :)

```
function validateForm() {
    var form = document.forms.myForm,
        x = form.uname.value,
        y = form.pass.value;

    if (x === null || x === "") {
        alert("UserName must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    if (y === null || y === "") {
        alert("Password must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT (in light of your comment):

If you own the second website, then the ethical and legal issues disappear. If both sites are hosted on the same server and you have direct access to the database, it really doesn't matter which website the account is created through.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible only if the site in which you want to create an account(for example google)
provides a service which you can call for creating the account. If the site provides any service then simply call the service and the account will be created.

But I don't think sites do provide such service, because they want users to create account by themselves and to stop malicious account creation they are using CAPTCHA. Providing search service is too dangerous for sites as this might break the server.